# IBAction selection of row in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a TableView each row will open the same screen but with different locations for the views.

I want the images to open up on each view in a random way.

i have a random method which takes care of that but i am not sure how to call this method upon selection of a row in the TableView - This same method should be called for every row.
At this moment i am randomizing each view with a button - after the view loads i need to press the button and then the images are randomized.

**Is there a way to call this method upon a selection of a row in the TableView?**

```
-(IBAction) randomizeLocations:(UIButton*)sender {

for (MyView* myv in rndArry) 
{
    int x;
    x = generateRandomNumber(); 

    while (usedRnd[x] == 1)
    {
        x = generateRandomNumber();            
    }

    myv.frame = rndArryloc[x];
    usedRnd[x] = 1;
}

int i;
for (i=0; i<8; i++) 
{
    usedRnd[i] = 0;
}
```

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        {
            OneViewController* ovc = [[OneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OneViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:ovc animated:YES];

           //  ???? WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE ????

            [ovc release];
        }
            break;

        ect....
```

Comment: Why don't you call your randomizer method in the viewDidLoad method of the OneViewController?

Comment: I'll assume, your randomizer class is named `grn` and you have a valid pointer to it, then do `[grn randomizeLocations :nil];`.

Comment: How would i call the Randomizer method in the ViewDidLoad ?

Comment: I do not have a class for the randomizer method, it is just a method place on the OneViewController.m file and declared on the OneViewController.h file  I AM NEW TO THIS SO SORRY FOR THE STUPID QUESTIONS - YOU NEED TO START FOR SOMEWHERE :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the great and fast answers -

i have read again and again and finally figured out what i needed to do.
As Holger wrote u did call the method in the ViewDidLoad and everything is working now.

Thanks again - This Forum Rules :)